# Hello world app for Nancy Framework does not compile

Tags: c#, nancy

I'm trying to get a hello world web application running with Nancy. It does not compile on and highlights the `Get["/"] = parameters => "Hello World";` and does not recognize this symbol.

I must be missing something simple but can't find anything on the web on this problem.

Steps:

1. Created a new ASP.NET Web Application
2. Using NuGet got and installed Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet
3. Checked that the web.config was configured by NuGet and it looks right
4. added a new class which has this code:

   ```
   using Nancy;

   namespace test2
   {
       public class MainModule : NancyModule
       {
           Get["/"] = parameters => "Hello World";
       }
   }
   ```

   Result: `Get["/"] = parameters => "Hello World";` doesn't compile

Comment: Can't find anything on the web? The 7 line sample on the nancyfx.org homepage should be enough to show you where you went wrong :-)

Answer (score 4):

You need to put your route declaration inside the constructor of the MainModule. Putting the declaration straight into the body, of the class, in not a valid C# syntax.

Answer (score 1):

As TheCodeJunkie mentions, `Get["/"] = parameters => "Hello World";`needs to be placed in a constructor for the class.

```
using Nancy;

namespace test2
{
    public class MainModule : NancyModule
    {
        public MainModule() {
            Get["/"] = parameters => "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, please note that the syntax changed for the more recent versions and the definition now looks like

```
Get("/", parameters => "Hello World");
```